# How to convert complex json to java object using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

How to convert complex json to java object using gson of google and my json is some thing like this:

```
{
    "error": "200",
    "status": "OK",
    "BarList": {
        "Bar1": {
            "Name": "yash",
            "sex": "male",
            "Type": "barowner",
            "userId": "x25df",
            "ContactNo": "1234567890",
            "zipCode": "110055",
            "Address": "Ghumtarastachaltigali",
            "Email": "nahihairee@gmail.com"
        },
        "Bar2": {
            "Name": "yash",
            "sex": "male",
            "Type": "barowner",
            "userId": "x25df",
            "ContactNo": "1234567890",
            "zipCode": "110055",
            "Address": "Ghumtarastachaltigali",
            "Email": "nahihairee@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

For mapping this json to my java object i have made 3 class 
First : BarListResponse - in which i did this:-

```
public class BarListResponse {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose(serialize = false)
    String errrocode;

    @Expose(serialize = false)
    String status;

    @SerializedName("data")
    Bar bar_list[];

    public String getErrrocode() {
        return errrocode;
    }

    public void setErrrocode(String errrocode) {
        this.errrocode = errrocode;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Bar[] getLst() {
        return bar_list;
    }

    public void setLst(Bar lst[]) {
        this.bar_list = lst;
    }
}
```

Second bar list :

```
public class BarList {

    @SerializedName("Bar")
    Bar bar[];

    public Bar[] getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar1(Bar bar[]) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

And third is

```
public class Bar {

    String Name;
    String sex;
    String type;
    String userId;
    double ContactNo;
    double zipCode;
    String Address;
    String Email;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }
    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public double getContactNo() {
        return ContactNo;
    }
    public void setContactNo(double contactNo) {
        ContactNo = contactNo;
    }
    public double getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
    public void setZipCode(double zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

and from this i want to fetch the details of the each bar one by one .

please help resolving this issue.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It's named BarList and not data.     @SerializedName("data")
    Bar bar_list[];

Comment: Did you try new Gson().fromJson(userinput, BarList.class);

Answer (score 0):

You can't map json objects ({ ... }) to java lists so you have to create for the "list" objects a own class to map the objects to. That is very sub-optimal because you have to create for each item in the list a own property in your class but if you have no control over the json you have to deal with it.

The classes should look like the following then **BarListResponse.java**:

```
public class BarListResponse {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose(serialize = false)
    String errrocode;

    @Expose(serialize = false)
    String status;

    @SerializedName("BarList")
    BarList bar_list;

    public String getErrrocode() {
        return errrocode;
    }

    public void setErrrocode(String errrocode) {
        this.errrocode = errrocode;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public BarList getLst() {
        return bar_list;
    }

    public void setLst(BarList lst) {
        this.bar_list = lst;
    }
}
```

**BarList.java**:

```
public class BarList {
    Bar Bar1;
    Bar Bar2;
    ...
}
```

If you have somehow control over the json output you could change the "BarList" to a json array:

```
{
    "error": "200",
    "status": "OK",
    "BarList": [
        {
            "Name": "yash",
            "sex": "male",
            "Type": "barowner",
            "userId": "x25df",
            "ContactNo": "1234567890",
            "zipCode": "110055",
            "Address": "Ghumtarastachaltigali",
            "Email": "nahihairee@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "Name": "yash",
            "sex": "male",
            "Type": "barowner",
            "userId": "x25df",
            "ContactNo": "1234567890",
            "zipCode": "110055",
            "Address": "Ghumtarastachaltigali",
            "Email": "nahihairee@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

And change the response class to the following:

```
public class BarListResponse {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose(serialize = false)
    String errrocode;

    @Expose(serialize = false)
    String status;

    @SerializedName("BarList")
    List<Bar> bar_list;

    public String getErrrocode() {
        return errrocode;
    }

    public void setErrrocode(String errrocode) {
        this.errrocode = errrocode;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Bar> getLst() {
        return bar_list;
    }

    public void setLst(List<Bar> lst) {
        this.bar_list = lst;
    }
}
```

With that approach you don't need an extra "BarList" class and the list can contain "unlimited" entries without changing you internal class structure.